# Jackson Mapping Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have request Payload of following structure:

```
{
"universityId": "u001",
"universityName": "myuniversity",
"departments": [
    {
        "departmentId": 1,
        "departmentName": "mydept",
        "students": [
            {
                "studentId": 405,
                "subCode": "02470",
                "studentName": "std nmae",
                "semester": [
                    {
                        "SemesterNo": 1,
                        "SemesterType": "odd",
                        "CGPA": 8,
                    },
                    {
                        "SemesterNo": 2,
                        "SemesterType": "even",
                        "CGPA": 8.2,
                    },
                    {
                        "SemesterNo": 3,
                        "SemesterType": "odd",
                        "CGPA": 8.5,
                    },
                    {
                        "SemesterNo": 4,
                        "SemesterType": "even",
                        "CGPA": 8.7,
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
  }
```

Now my corresponding java class is of following type:

```
public class University{
   .......
   List<Dept> departments;
}
public class Dept{
   .......
   List<Student> students;
}
public class Student{
   .......
   List<Semester> semester;
}
public class Semester{
   .......
}
```

**Now all the data is getting mapped except `List<Semester> semester`**

I am using Spring RestController and mapping using `@RequestBody`.

Can anyone provide any solution to this?

Comment: can you show the object Semester? the names might not match

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Request JSON mapping Spring uses getter and setter to set the properties of RequestBody Object.

1. Does Student have getter or setter of List?
   if have setterName should be same as JSON key semester 
   oR 
   use

> `@JsonProperty("semester")`
>     List semester;

2. These below also need to be taken care of although not related to question.

   "semester": [ {
                           "SemesterNo": 1,
                           "SemesterType": "odd",
                           "CGPA": 8,
                       },
                ]

a. correct it as JSON is invalid no comma should be after "CGPA": 8.

b. semester should be semesterNo as Spring will use setterName to set the value which is by default camel case with first letter small 
OR if want to use SemesterNo then use with `@JsonProperty("SemesterNo")`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@JsonProperty("semester")`. This annotation also helps when you want to have a different variable name from the JSON field. For more reference view [this resource](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-name-of-property).

Moreover rectify the unnecessary commas after the values of CGPA. for building of POJO classes, [jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)